# I saved these seeds last year, but I cannot remember what they are. Some sort of flower

Tags: identification, seeds

They are about 1/4" long. Have five division lined that I can see. Hard cost that is a bit lumpy.  Almost round, but a bit oval shape. Bark brown to black in color. Some kind of flower.

[image]

Comment: Where in the world was the plant growing?

Comment: Grow them and see...

Answer (score 3):

I pretty sure that they're [Four o'Clocks](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.S3Kz7JclvaQIwTBuTvOnWAHaJQ%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=8edb5aadc8c29f5f01a95616cdf6a1400dfb85bb5393fbd4d36b2bc8479935a4&ipo=images) (*Mirabilis jalapa*). See [here](https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6301969/il_fullxfull.271492863.jpg) for a photo of their seeds.

[image: Montage of Four o'Clocks]